# Define global hyphenation for words containing numbers

Tags: hyphenation

In my thesis a have a lot of occurences of the word like ABC2011abc and I want them to be hyphenated as `ABC2011\-abc`.

Is it possible to define a global hyphenation rule, like say with `\hyphenation`?

Search and replace would be a last measure and feels very un-LaTeX.

Comment: How about defining a macro for this? `\newcommand{\ABC2011abc}{ABC2011\-abc}`

Comment: @Raphink: Numbers are not allowed in macro names. Nevertheless, your idea to define a macro is good. Just the name must be changed a little.

Comment: @Raphink: You should put your (corrected) suggestion in an answer, so that the community can upvote it.

Answer (score 13):

Since `\hypenation` doesn't take numbers, you could define a macro for it:

```
\newcommand{\ABCTwoZeroElevenabc}{ABC2011\-abc}
```

and use it everytime you want to typeset this word.

Comment: You might want to add `\xspace` from the `xspace` package at the end of the replacement text, otherwise you have to add `{}` after the macro to avoid the removal of following spaces. Also I would use a short macro name, otherwise it's easier to type the `\-` by hand.

Comment: @Martin: thanks for the suggestion of using `xspace`. I'm actually used to adding `{}` after most macros when I call them, since this is how many standard (e.g. frenchb) macros behave. There's still an advantage of using a macro over adding `\-` manually, which is to modify the macro later on if required.

Comment: @Tobi: As @Martin said, you can change the macro name (without using digits though) to make it easier to type.

Comment: I just got bitten by a global search and replace to put the macros i defined in place. I think it's going to be a lot easier to just replace the overflowing occurrences of the words just before printing.

Comment: How so bitten ?

Comment: Filenames of graphics and labels that are uses all over the document contain those words too.

Comment: Hmmm, use regexs with `\b` to prevent modifying words that *contain* this pattern?

Comment: @tobi: if the solution fits you, you can check it.

Answer (score 6):

A variant on Raphink's answer: define a macro like

```
\def\ABC2011abc{ABC2011\-abc}
```

(i.e. *not* using `\newcommand`).  This makes a "delimited macro" using a plain TeX construction, where the 2011abc part is not actually in the name of the macro but is required to be present when the macro is expanded.  The actual name of the macro is `\ABC`, so this is prone to unexpected errors if you also define `\ABC2011cde`, however.

For some reason, this gives bizarre results using `\newcommand`, probably because of how it internally processes the macro name to check that it was not previously defined.